# Magento Configurable products don't go out of stock

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I have the usual configurable-simple products store. Ideally I would like that a configurable products should automatically go out of stock when all of its associated products go out of stock. How ever this does not seem to happen. Am I missing something in the configuration or is this not supported?

I am using magento community 1.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's not supported. I have similar problem and I use this code to eliminate out of stock products:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

sulabh
First check your inventory configuration for every product ("manage stock") should be set to true.
Then run stock reindex. It will check if every child is out of stock -> will set configurable product out of stock.

Comment: "manage stock" is set to true. does magento check this only on reindex?

Comment: no, it do so on saving also.
Check your inventory settings also. ("display out of stock products" in config).<br>
It could be some customization of course.